# Selenium how to open a web browser to run a selenium script

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I exported a script from **selenium IDE 1.9.0** as Java/TestNG/RemoteControl.

I would like to run this script using **TestNG** within **Eclipse** and I want to see the script play back in **Firefox** browser.

I did some search online, but I could not make it work. I need some instructions and guidance on how to make the code work. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.testng.annotations.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.htmlunit.HtmlUnitDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import static org.testng.Assert.*;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;

public class search_donor_suzy_ng //extends SeleneseTestNgHelper {
    @BeforeTest
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        //initizlize Firefoxbrowser: 
        WebDriver ffoxdriver = new FirefoxDriver();
        String baseUrl = "www.google.com"; //sample URL
    }
    @Test 
    public void testSearch_donor_suzy_ng() throws Exception {
        // set overall speed of the test case
        selenium.setSpeed("4000");
        selenium.open("/?html=openid");
        selenium.click("css=input[type=\"submit\"]");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        selenium.type("id=edit-name", "jeffshu");
        selenium.type("id=edit-pass", "tEgvz9xsaNjnwe4Y");
        selenium.click("id=edit-submit");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        Thread.sleep(4000);
        selenium.click("id=cmp_admin");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.click("id=quicksearch_anchor");
        selenium.click("css=img[alt=\"Member\"]");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
        selenium.type("id=search_name", "suzy");
        selenium.click("css=input[type=\"image\"]");
        selenium.click("link=Balagia, Suzy");
        selenium.waitForPageToLoad("30000");
    }
    @AfterTest
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        ffoxdriver.quit();  
    }
}
```

Comment: @user1177636, thanks for the reply. I will read Selenium documentation on Selenium RC. Could you tell me why you recommend Webdriver over Selenium RC? Thanks!

Comment: Hello, user1177636, I exported the Selenium 1 code as Junit/WebDriver and I did some modification and it worked. Thanks for the advises!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you do need to refer to the documentation @ http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp

In your code, you are intializing the driver object in your beforetest method, which you are not using.  Driver is Webdriver's way of launching your browser, whereas in your testmethod you are using selenium and selenium 1 commands.  As a quick step, you can replace your selenium with driver (put your declaration of driver in class scope and method scope).  SeleneseTestngHelper is also selenium1.
Make sure you have the necessary webdriver jars in your project.

Certain commands in webdriver are different than selenium 1 and you might see compile erros when you do the replacement.  Look at the methods available with driver. and use corresponding commands eg. Use get() of webdriver instead of open().  You can refer the [javadocs](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebDriver.htmle) for this or use your ide to get to know these.

Comment: thanks for the advises, I exported the code as Junit4/WedDriver and run the code as Junit test, it worked the same way as I executed the script from Selenium IDE. Thanks!